# HashAggregate got slow perfomance

Tags: postgresql

I have a table likse this:
[image]

my index is id_station_date_hour

My query:

```
select id_station,area_type,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and(zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special) > 0 and date >= '2017-10-01' and date <= '2017-10-31' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special else 0 end) as ex_z1z2z3z4z5_time,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and(zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special) > 0 and date >= '2017-10-01' and date <= '2017-10-31' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as ex_z1z2z3z4z5_num,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and(zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special) > 0 and date >= '2017-08-31' and date <= '2017-09-30' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special else 0 end) as ex_z1z2z3z4z5_time_prev,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and(zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special) > 0 and date >= '2017-08-31' and date <= '2017-09-30' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as ex_z1z2z3z4z5_num_prev,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and (zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special) >= 180 and (zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special) < 360 and date >= '2017-10-01' and date <= '2017-10-31' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special else 0 end) as ex_z1z2z3z4z5_num_3to6,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and (zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special) >= 180 and (zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special) < 360 and date >= '2017-08-31' and date <= '2017-09-30' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as ex_z1z2z3z4z5_num_3to6_prev,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and (zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special) >= 360 and (zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special) < 600 and date >= '2017-10-01' and date <= '2017-10-31' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special else 0 end) as ex_z1z2z3z4z5_num_6to10,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and (zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special) >= 360 and (zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special) < 600 and date >= '2017-08-31' and date <= '2017-09-30' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as ex_z1z2z3z4z5_num_6to10_prev,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and (zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special) < 180 and date >= '2017-10-01' and date <= '2017-10-31' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special else 0 end) as ex_z1z2z3z4z5_num_less3,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and (zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special) < 180 and date >= '2017-08-31' and date <= '2017-09-30' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as ex_z1z2z3z4z5_num_less3_prev,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and (zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special) >= 60 and (zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special) < 180 and date >= '2017-10-01' and date <= '2017-10-31' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special else 0 end) as ex_z1z2z3z4z5_num_1to3,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and (zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special) >= 60 and (zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special) < 180 and date >= '2017-08-31' and date <= '2017-09-30' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as ex_z1z2z3z4z5_num_1to3_prev,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and (zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special) >= 600 and (zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special) < 900 and date >= '2017-10-01' and date <= '2017-10-31' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special else 0 end) as ex_z1z2z3z4z5_num_10to15,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and (zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special) >= 600 and (zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special) < 900 and date >= '2017-08-31' and date <= '2017-09-30' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as ex_z1z2z3z4z5_num_10to15_prev,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and (zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special) < 60 and date >= '2017-10-01' and date <= '2017-10-31' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special else 0 end) as ex_z1z2z3z4z5_num_less1,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and (zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special) < 60 and date >= '2017-08-31' and date <= '2017-09-30' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as ex_z1z2z3z4z5_num_less1_prev,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and (zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special) >= 900 and date >= '2017-10-01' and date <= '2017-10-31' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special else 0 end) as ex_z1z2z3z4z5_num_over15,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and (zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special) >= 900 and date >= '2017-08-31' and date <= '2017-09-30' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as ex_z1z2z3z4z5_num_over15_prev,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and (zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special) >= 600 and date >= '2017-10-01' and date <= '2017-10-31' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special else 0 end) as ex_z1z2z3z4z5_num_over10,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and (zone1+zone2+zone3+cashiertime+special) >= 600 and date >= '2017-08-31' and date <= '2017-09-30' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as ex_z1z2z3z4z5_num_over10_prev,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and type = 1 and date >= '2017-10-01' and date <= '2017-10-31' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as man,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and type = 2 and date >= '2017-10-01' and date <= '2017-10-31' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as woman,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and type = 3 and date >= '2017-10-01' and date <= '2017-10-31' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as couple,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and type = 4 and date >= '2017-10-01' and date <= '2017-10-31' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as boy,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and type = 5 and date >= '2017-10-01' and date <= '2017-10-31' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as girl,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and type = 6 and date >= '2017-10-01' and date <= '2017-10-31' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as young_couple,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and type = 7 and date >= '2017-10-01' and date <= '2017-10-31' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as old_man,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and type = 8 and date >= '2017-10-01' and date <= '2017-10-31' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as old_woman,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and type = 9 and date >= '2017-10-01' and date <= '2017-10-31' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as old_couple,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and type = 10 and date >= '2017-10-01' and date <= '2017-10-31' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as family,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and type = 10 and date >= '2017-10-01' and date <= '2017-10-31' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then family_total else 0 end) as family_total,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and type = 11 and date >= '2017-10-01' and date <= '2017-10-31' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as group,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and type = 11 and date >= '2017-10-01' and date <= '2017-10-31' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then group_man else 0 end) as group_man,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and type = 11 and date >= '2017-10-01' and date <= '2017-10-31' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then group_woman else 0 end) as group_woman,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and type = 12 and date >= '2017-10-01' and date <= '2017-10-31' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as empty,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and date >= '2017-10-01' and date <= '2017-10-31' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as total_entries,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and type = 1 and date >= '2017-08-31' and date <= '2017-09-30' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as man_prev,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and type = 2 and date >= '2017-08-31' and date <= '2017-09-30' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as woman_prev,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and type = 3 and date >= '2017-08-31' and date <= '2017-09-30' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as couple_prev,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and type = 4 and date >= '2017-08-31' and date <= '2017-09-30' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as boy_prev,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and type = 5 and date >= '2017-08-31' and date <= '2017-09-30' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as girl_prev,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and type = 6 and date >= '2017-08-31' and date <= '2017-09-30' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as young_couple_prev,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and type = 7 and date >= '2017-08-31' and date <= '2017-09-30' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as old_man_prev,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and type = 8 and date >= '2017-08-31' and date <= '2017-09-30' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as old_woman_prev,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and type = 9 and date >= '2017-08-31' and date <= '2017-09-30' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as old_couple_prev,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and type = 10 and date >= '2017-08-31' and date <= '2017-09-30' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as family_prev,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and type = 10 and date >= '2017-08-31' and date <= '2017-09-30' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then family_total else 0 end) as family_total_prev,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and type = 11 and date >= '2017-08-31' and date <= '2017-09-30' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as grou_prev,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and type = 11 and date >= '2017-08-31' and date <= '2017-09-30' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then group_man else 0 end) as group_man_prev,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and type = 11 and date >= '2017-08-31' and date <= '2017-09-30' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then group_woman else 0 end) as group_woman_prev,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and type = 12 and date >= '2017-08-31' and date <= '2017-09-30' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as empty_prev,
sum(case when goinside = 1 and date >= '2017-08-31' and date <= '2017-09-30' and hour >= 9 and hour < 22 then 1 else 0 end) as total_entries_prev 
from data_1034_detail where id_station IN (2399,2397) AND ((date >= '2017-10-01' and date <= '2017-10-31' AND hour >= 9 and hour < 22) OR (date >= '2017-08-31' and date <= '2017-09-30' AND hour >= 9 and hour < 22)) group by id_station, area_type
```

actually all fields selected area different condition, so it will make the query speed working slowly if I add more condition and selected fields. How can I set up proper index in this case?

Explain:

```
'HashAggregate  (cost=304337.96..304338.36 rows=40 width=428) (actual time=7233.402..7233.449 rows=37 loops=1)'
'  Group Key: id_station, area_type'
'  ->  Seq Scan on data_1034_detail  (cost=0.00..17573.72 rows=218904 width=64) (actual time=0.035..394.334 rows=282899 loops=1)'
'        Filter: ((id_station = ANY ('{2399,2397}'::bigint[])) AND (hour >= 9) AND (hour < 22) AND (((date >= '2017-10-01'::date) AND (date <= '2017-10-31'::date)) OR ((date >= '2017-08-31'::date) AND (date <= '2017-09-30'::date))))'
'Planning time: 0.735 ms'
'Execution time: 7234.169 ms'
```

And any chance to make this query execute in 1s?

Comment: This will really depends about the diversity of your id_station in the table for example. Sometime it's more quicker to have an index only on id_station, and another one on date. You need to make some tests with the explain, as for the moment your index is not used. Separate index could be more successfull. Don't know also if you do this query by hand or generated by code, but a CTE query to remove the OR, in two different query for each period could be also more efficient to use an index on date.

Answer (score 0):

It is the arithmetic that makes the query slow.

I am not sure, but maybe you can win some if you use a `FILTER` clause with the summation.

Instead of

```
sum(CASE WHEN goinside = 1
              AND (zone1 + zone2 + zone3 + cashiertime + special) > 0
              AND date >= '2017-10-01'
              AND date <= '2017-10-31'
              AND hour >= 9
              AND hour < 22
         THEN zone1 + zone2 + zone3 + cashiertime + special
         ELSE 0
    END) AS ex_z1z2z3z4z5_time
```

you could write:

```
sum(zone1 + zone2 + zone3 + cashiertime + special)
   FILTER (WHERE goinside = 1
             AND (zone1 + zone2 + zone3 + cashiertime + special) > 0
             AND date >= '2017-10-01'
             AND date <= '2017-10-31'
             AND hour >= 9
             AND hour < 22) AS ex_z1z2z3z4z5_time
```

You will still have to do all the calculations, but the sum will be over fewer items.

Perhaps [PG-Strom](http://strom.kaigai.gr.jp/) can help you here – this extension delegates operations that can be parallelized to the GPU.

Comment: cool! Laurenz, the query speed now down to 4.6s, but it still not enough for me.

Comment: anyway PG-Strom is available for Postgre9.6.6 yet?, Im using this version

Comment: PG-Strom has been around for a while, so I'd expect that it is available for PostgreSQL 9.6. You probably have to build it yourself. I have never used it, so I cannot provide detailed help.